# JavaFX setOnEndOfMedia on next MediaPlayer

Tags: javafx, media, mediaview

I have `List<MediaPlayer>` that is populating by

```
private List<MediaPlayer> players() {

    for (String file : path.list((dir1, name) -> {
        if (name.endsWith(SUPPORTED_VIDEO_FILE_EXTENSIONS)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    })) {
        players.add(createPlayer(Paths.get(path + "/" + file).toUri().toString()));
        System.out.println(Paths.get(path + "/" + file).toUri().toString());
    }
    return players;
}
```

In my case size of `List<MediaPlayer>` is 3. Than i use it there

```
if (currentNumOfVideo == -1) {
    currentNumOfVideo = 0;
}
mv = new MediaView();
MediaPlayer currentPlayer = players.get(currentNumOfVideo);
mv.setMediaPlayer(currentPlayer);
currentPlayer.play();

players.get(currentNumOfVideo).setOnEndOfMedia(() -> {
    players.get(currentNumOfVideo).stop();
    if (currentNumOfVideo < players.size()) {
        currentNumOfVideo += 1;
        mv.setMediaPlayer(players.get(currentNumOfVideo));
        players.get(currentNumOfVideo).play();
    } else {
        currentNumOfVideo = 0;
        mv.setMediaPlayer(players.get(currentNumOfVideo));
        players.get(currentNumOfVideo).play();
    }
});
```

First video playing, when it ends second video starts. After second video MediaPlayer stops and didn't play third video.

I understand that because of my `setOnEndOfMedia` that is only on first MediaPlayer. When the second video starts it doesn't have `setOnEndOfMedia`. How can I `setOnEndOfMedia` on every video in my `List<MediaPlayer>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would not create all the `MediaPlayer` instances ahead-of-time. Instead, get a list of `Media` objects or at least the URIs pointing to the media. Then create a method which is responsible for playing the next video when the current video ends. That method will dispose the old `MediaPlayer`, create the next `MediaPlayer`, and configure it to call the same method upon completion. For example:

```java
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

  private MediaView mediaView;

  private List<Media> media;
  private int curIndex;

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    media = ...; // get media from somewhere

    mediaView = new MediaView();
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(mediaView), 720, 480));
    primaryStage.show();

    playNextVideo();
  }

  private void playNextVideo() {
    disposePlayer();
    if (curIndex == media.size()) {
      return; // no more videos to play
    }

    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media.get(curIndex++));
    player.setAutoPlay(true); // play ASAP
    player.setOnEndOfMedia(this::playNextVideo); // play next video when this one ends
    mediaView.setMediaPlayer(player);
  }

  private void disposePlayer() {
    MediaPlayer player = mediaView.getMediaPlayer();
    if (player != null) {
      player.dispose(); // release resources
    }
  }
}
```

This may cause a pause between videos. If that's not acceptable you could create the *next* `MediaPlayer` ahead-of-time, either at the same time as the current `MediaPlayer` or when the current player reaches a certain timestamp (e.g. 10 seconds before the end). But I still wouldn't create *all* the `MediaPlayer` instances ahead-of-time.

Comment: I love you! You made sense of the hours I spent trying to solve this.